# How to predict edges of a tree which also occur in the inverse of the tree.

Tags: graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I have a tree with an invertible adjacency matrix. I know a tree has a invertable matrix if the tree has a unique perfect matching.
I take the inverted adjacency matrix of the tree and replace all -1 with a 1, so every such inverse can be understood as an adjacency matrix of a graph. This way I get the inverse of the tree, if I understood correctly.
How can I find out which edges the tree and its inverse have in common?

I have found that the edges between the leaves and the neighboring edge also appear in the inverse of the tree.
However, there are other edges which are present in both graphs. In the middle of the tree as well as in its inverse without being adjacent to a leaf.
How do I recognize these without drawing the inverse of the tree?
There must be a certain pattern, i think.

Comment: See https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~combosem/abstract-guo.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the hint. If i get this right: The edges between the formed pairs of vertices in the inverse are preserved, but the vertices of the pair exchange their position in the graph. These edges are created with a 1 in the tree inverse. Also the edges between the vertices pairs remain, but the edges are connected to the other vertices of the pair. The edges between the vertices pairs are generated in the tree inverse from a -1 of the inverted adjacency matrix of the tree. There are some edges in the invers which can not be predicted by this method. Is this correct or am i missing something?